# selecting row base on date range of 2 inputs

Tags: mysql

I would like to select a row from the database based on two input text and named **date_start** and **date_end** where this 2 inputs are in the range of two fields of a row named **db_start** and **db_end**.

the 2 input must be exactly in a range of db_start and db_date.

can someone show me how to do it ?

**input :**

date_start : 2012-12-02

date_end   : 2012-12-19

**database (1 row)**

db_start   : 2012-01-01

db_end     : 2012-12-12

Comment: What have you tried? Can you give some example data and show what results you want for your example? Perhaps you could even make a http://sqlfiddle.com/ from your example data to make it easier for us to test our answers.

Comment: It sounds like you want to use [`BETWEEN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
('2012-12-02' BETWEEN db_start AND db_end) AND
('2012-12-19' BETWEEN db_start AND db_end)
```

Is this what you want?